# How to pick an individual based on the latest date

Tags: r

I have a dataset where some individuals are listed twice because they have received one or more degrees. I am wanting to only get the latest graduation date for each individual. Below are examples of what is currently happening and the desired output.

```
People |  g_date  | 
PersonA|2019-01-01|
PersonA|2020-01-01|
PersonB|2010-05-01|
PersonB|2015-01-01|
PersonC|2010-06-01|

People |  g_date  |
PersonA|2020-01-01|
PersonB|2015-01-01|
Personc|2010-06-01|
```

Comment: Assuming your data is already sorted by `g_date`, `your_data[!duplicated(your_data$People, fromLast = TRUE), ]`. By default `!duplicated` will keep the first occurrence. With `fromLast = TRUE` it will keep that last occurrence.

Comment: It is not sorted by g_date. How would I do that?

Comment: `your_data <- your_data[order(your_data$g_date), ]`

Comment: Alternately, if you like `library(dplyr)`, then `your_data %>% arrange(g_date) %>% filter(!duplicated(People, fromLast = TRUE))`